# Need Validation Error Message if i try to select drop down list when check box= unchecked

Tags: javascript, html

i have 7 drop downs in in table row and if try to select a value in drop downs when check box =un checked it show show some validation message.
 I need a Validation error message at the drop down it should show like "Please enable check box".
if check box = checked all drop down lists able to work properly.
i tried this please help me.

```js
function enableddl(chkddl) {
  var dd1 = document.getElementById("DDL1");
  var dd2 = document.getElementById("DDL2");
  var dd3 = document.getElementById("DDL3");
  var dd4 = document.getElementById("DDL4");
  var dd5 = document.getElementById("DDL5");
  var dd6 = document.getElementById("DDL6");
  var dd7 = document.getElementById("DDL7");

  dd1.disabled = chkddl.checked ? false : true;
  dd2.disabled = chkddl.checked ? false : true;
  dd3.disabled = chkddl.checked ? false : true;
  dd4.disabled = chkddl.checked ? false : true;
  dd5.disabled = chkddl.checked ? false : true;
  dd6.disabled = chkddl.checked ? false : true;
  dd7.disabled = chkddl.checked ? false : true;

  if (!dd1.disabled && !dd2.disabled && !dd3.disabled && !dd4.disabled && !dd5.disabled && !dd6.disabled && !dd7.disabled) {
    dd1.focus();
    dd2.focus();
    dd3.focus();
    dd4.focus();
    dd5.focus();
    dd6.focus();
    dd7.focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chkddl" onclick="enableddl(this)" required="">
<select id="DDL1" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="" selected="">yes</option>
  <option>no</option>
</select>
<select id="DDL2" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="" selected="">yes</option>
  <option>no</option>
</select>
<select id="DDL3" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="" selected="">yes</option>
  <option>no</option>
</select>
<select id="DDL4" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="" selected="">yes</option>
  <option>no</option>
</select>
<select id="DDL5" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="" selected="">yes</option>
  <option>no</option>
</select>
<select id="DDL6" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="" selected="">yes</option>
  <option>no</option>
</select>
<select id="DDL7" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="" selected="">yes</option>
  <option>no</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sidenote: I'd strongly suggest looking at loops. Any time you find yourself writing repeated, almost identical code, always suspect there's a better way.

Comment: your drop downs are disabled and are enabled only when you are selecting checkbox. However to add check at drop down level write function on change `<select id="DDL1" onchange="validateDD()">` in that function check for drop down value `function validateDD(el)
{
 var selectedValue = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
    if (selectedValue == "")
   {
    alert("Please select a checkbox");
   }
}`

Comment: Not sure if the error you are seeing is caused by this, but you have a variable name mismatch `ddl` vs `dd1` notice the `l` (lowercase "L")  and `1`  (number "1").

Comment: <select id="DDL1" onchange="validateDD()">
 function validateDD(el)
 { var selectedValue = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
 if (selectedValue == "") { alert("Please select a checkbox"); } }
bro, but in this code we are not checking for check box?

Answer (score 1):

In you function `enableddl()` you defined `var ddl = document.getElementById("DDL1");` but in you if check you are calling as `dd1`.
Change `var ddl = document.getElementById("DDL1");` to 
`var dd1 = document.getElementById("DDL1");`

Answer (score 1):

```
let allDropDown = document.querySelectorAll('select');

    for (var i = 0; i < allDropDown.length; i++) {
      let getElement = allDropDown[i].getAttribute("id");

    if(document.getElementById(getElement).value=''){
       // add code to show error message using "element.innerHTML"   
    }
}
```

Comment: But where is the condition for check box